PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted while exporting view using Data export module
I am trying to export a view of size <50k using views data export module but I'm getting memory size exhausted error.
Memory limit is already 1024MB, can't increase that. Is there any solution for this?

Reading the issues in the modules issue queue, there seems to be a "batched export" option, try that.
